# Trying to pass a list to a form by value not reference

Tags: c#

Working on a project where I am storing my data using a GenericList, based off a class I created which contains a handful of string members.  This works great, but things get troublesome when I try to pass this list to a second form.  I initially setup a get/set block in the second form to accept the list and then return it, but the destination is always null.  As a workaround I changed the local list on the second form to public and am able to access it that way, but then instead of getting a copy of the list, I get ByRef passing so any changes made are reflected in the master list.  Since I want to be able to not accept these changes, I really want this to be a pass by value.  These two problems have to be linked...

Here is the setup.  In form1 I have this definition at the class level, making this somewhat of a global variable (yeah its bad, but it works for me):

```
private List<ServerList> theServerList = new List<ServerList>();
```

Later on I create the new form and (try to) pass my data into it using:

```
frmEditor theEditor = new frmEditor();
theEditor.updatedServerList = theServerList;
DialogResult res = theEditor.ShowDialog();
```

On the second from, I have this to receive the data:

```
private List<ServerList> myServerList = new List<ServerList>();

public List<ServerList> updatedServerList
{
    get { return myServerList; }
    set { myServerList = updatedServerList; }
}
```

This results a list on form2 (the myServerList) always being empty.  Since this was not working, I commented out all these lines and changed the myServerList definition on form2 to public.  Now after instantiating form2 I am able to get the data over by doing this:

```
theEditor.myServerList = theServerList;
```

This works in that the data nicely shows up form2, but this kind of an assignment just copies the pointer of the data block in memory from one variable to the other (basically a ByRef passing), so any changes I make on form2 change "both" lists since they are the same.  I would like to have a local copy in form2 so I can make changes and then accept them or not depending of if the user clicks Cancel (drop all changes), or OK (copy the local data from form2 back to form1).

Comment: Are you trying to make sure changes to the list itself does not affect the original, or also trying to make sure changes to the objects inside the list are not affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original does not work because your setter should be:

```
public List<ServerList> updatedServerList
{
    get { return myServerList; }
    set { myServerList = value; }
}
```

If you want to copy the list, you can use `ToList` on the incoming value:

```
public List<ServerList> updatedServerList
{
    get { return myServerList; }
    set { myServerList = value.ToList(); }
}
```

This is not to do with 'by value' vs 'by reference' since `List<T>` is a reference type, so the value of a variable of type `List<ServerList>` is a reference which is copied into the setter method. This reference will point to the same object in both the caller and receiver classes. If you want to copy the contents of the list you need to do it manually using `ToList` or similar.

Comment: "If you want to copy the contents of the list you need to do it manually using ToList or similar" -- Beware that if `ServerList` is a reference type then any modifications to the *items* of the new, copied list will modify the equivalent objects in the original list.